# Using UIScrollView to show different views flipping

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview, mono, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to use a `UIScrollView` in addition to `UIPageControl` to show a paging image of sorts. It will be a mock version of a Record Sleeve, but Im not sure how to make the views page. I have a table on the first section, and it works correctly, but I don't know how to add to the second. I don't want to do it in code, I want to do it in the nib. I'm using mono touch and **Xamarin** so I know things will be different. I just need the best practice to add a subview to the `UIScrollView`, and also make it compatible with all iPhone models.